# datamaps plot lines from ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, d3.js

I am trying to plot lines from an ajax call using datamaps/d3.

```
    var map = new Datamap({
                element: document.getElementById('container'),
                        scope: 'usa',

                });
 map.arc([
 {
  origin: {
      latitude: 40.229922,   // <-- I want these to be dynamic based on ajax
      longitude: -79.778889  // <-- I want these to be dynamic based on ajax
  },
  destination: {
      latitude: 38.818889,   // <-- I want these to be dynamic based on ajax
      longitude: -77.575    // <-- I want these to be dynamic based on ajax
  }
 },
{
  options: {
    strokeWidth: 14,
    strokeColor: 'rgba(100, 10, 200, 0.4)',
 greatArc: true 
  }
 },
],  {strokeWidth: 1, arcSharpness: 1.4});
```

how can i loop through a json response using ajax to set multiple origin/destinations?  what would i put in the maps.arc section of the code?

my ajax response:

```
{"1":{"origin":{"lat":"42.229922","lon":"-78.229922"},
      "destination":{"lat":"31.229922","lon":"-84.229922"}},
 "2":{"origin":{"lat":"47.229922","lon":"-69.229922"},
      "destination":{"lat":"44.229922","lon":"-74.229922"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred solution would be to modify your ajax response to better fit the required data format:

- make it an array of objects, not an object of objects.
- latitude and longitude properties should be numbers not strings
- lat and lon should be spelled out

If you can't or won't change the output the less efficient solution is to coerce in JavaScript:

```
// retrieve the json
d3.json('data.json', function(d) {
  var arcs = []; // array of parsed arcs
  for (var key in d) {
    var obj = d[key]; // get our inner object
    arcs.push({
      origin: {
        latitude: +obj.origin.lat, //convert to numbers
        longitude: +obj.origin.lon
      },
      destination: {
        latitude: +obj.destination.lat,
        longitude: +obj.destination.lon
      },
      options: {
        strokeWidth: 1,
        strokeColor: 'rgba(100, 10, 200, 0.4)',
        greatArc: true
      } // tack on options for each one
    });

    map.arc(arcs, {
      strokeWidth: 5,
      arcSharpness: 1.4
    }); // finally call .arc
  }
});
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ftpWwwW0t8ewmg0WazZY?p=preview).

**Note**, you don't need jquery here at all.

Comment: i will have to try this in a bit, but looks like what im looking for.  Question.  you use "data.json" as your source.  That source is dynamic to me, hence the ajax call. how can i incorporate the ajax call to this?

Comment: @bart2puck, that is the url to the endpoint generating the json.  In my example just a file, for you though I am guessing a web service.